# PHP-FPM upstream error with ipv6

Tags: 20.04, nginx, ipv6, php7, ipv4

I have just installed the latest Nginx with PHP7.4-fpm on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04.2 server.

I added a virtual host that has a WordPress site on it and it is loading fine but I noticed the nginx logs bombarded with errors like the following:

`[error] 183472#183472: *625 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xxx.xxx.xx, server: example.com, request: "GET /some-page-name/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://[::1]:8001", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/"`

On googling about this, I found out from the **second answer** on this [ServerFault thread](https://serverfault.com/a/576488/300041) that it was because I am using an ipv6 address and that I could fix it by replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` in the nginx server block files since `fastcgi://[::1]:8001` won't work.

I made the changes in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf` and changed the following line:

`fastcgi_pass localhost:8001;`

To:

`fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8001;`

And according to a comment on that same **ServerFault** answer, in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, I changed the following line:

`listen 80 default_server;`

To:

`listen 0.0.0.0:80 default_server;`

However, after making the above changes and restarting nginx & php7.4-fpm, if I check the PHP execution mode in my server control panel (Virtualmin), neither of the available two options `FCGId` or `FPM` is being used.

When I choose FPM and click save, the `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8001;` line in the nginx server block file reverts back to `fastcgi_pass localhost:8001;` and the above errors starts showing up again.

The `listen 0.0.0.0:80 default_server;` wasn't reverted back on restarting nginx or fpm however.

How do I instruct FPM to use the ipv4 address instead of the ipv6 address?

**N.B.** I have tried changing `listen = /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock` to `listen = 127.0.0.1:8000` in `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` and then following the above steps but that didn't help either and the same thing happen.

---

**P.S.** This issue isn't related to the control panel I used since there are quite a few ServerFault posts and multiple forum threads online that seems to be related to this issue when they try to use PHP-FPM with a dual-stack ipv4/ipv6 setup apparently.